# ApiPlatform - custom action with dbal query

Tags: php, api, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

Maybe I don't understand this idea but I'm starting create my first test app that use api platform.

I have custom action for my search:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     path="/api/pharmacies/search",
 *     name="pharmacy_search",
 *     defaults={
 *         "_api_resource_class"=Pharmacy::class,
 *         "_api_collection_operation_name"="search"
 *     }
 * )
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Paginator
 */
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $query = SearchQuery::createFromRequest($request);

    return $this->pharmacyRepository->search($query);
}
```

and method in the repository:

```
public function search(SearchQuery $searchQuery: Paginator
{

    $firstResult = ($searchQuery->getPage() - 1) * self::ITEMS_PER_PAGE;

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    /...
        ->setFirstResult($firstResult)
        ->setMaxResults(self::ITEMS_PER_PAGE);

    $doctrinePaginator = new DoctrinePaginator($qb, false);

    return new Paginator($doctrinePaginator);
}
```

And it works fine but this action doesn't need all field form the entity and relations to other tables. Currently this action creates 22 queries. I'd like create query in the DBAL/QueryBuilder and return pagination object with DTO.

```
public function search(SearchQuery $searchQuery)
{
    .../
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p.id')
        ->addSelect('p.name')/....

    $rows = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

    foreach ($rows as $row){
        $data[] = new SearchPharmacy($row['id'], $row['name']);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

The above code will work but if the response isn't Pagination object and I don't have `hydra:totalItems`, `hydra:next` etc in the response.

In theory I can use DataTransformer and transform entity to DTO, but this way can't allow simplify database queries.

Can I achieve this?

Comment: DTO patterns and Normalizers are used to hydrate / dehydrate objects in api-platform. What you need is custom filter on your base object and then modify your query with decorator. This way you allow api-platform to use all existing features without introducing complexity

Comment: Role of custom controller and DTO or Normalizers requires manual hydration  of Entity objects. It's useful when you are not using doctrine as your dbal and have custom database interface.  Api-platform is such complex that there are multiple ways to do same thing and you need to choose right way to do the task that is efficient. Custom filter simply overrides query when applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to use dbal query and mapped the result on a DTO, but I know how to add custom select, return it like a scalar:

```
public function search(SearchQuery $searchQuery): Paginator
{
    $firstResult = ($searchQuery->getPage() - 1) * self::ITEMS_PER_PAGE;

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p.id')
        ->addSelect('p.name')
        ->where('p.name LIKE :search')
        ->setParameter('search', "%" . $searchQuery->getSearch() . "%");

    $query = $qb->getQuery()->setFirstResult($firstResult)
        ->setMaxResults(self::ITEMS_PER_PAGE);

    $doctrinePaginator = new DoctrinePaginator($query, false);
    $doctrinePaginator->setUseOutputWalkers(false);

    return new Paginator($doctrinePaginator);
}
```

It finally I have 2 light queries, selected field from entity and Pagination.

Sources:

- https://github.com/APY/APYDataGridBundle/issues/931
- https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/cookbook/dql-custom-walkers.html